# Is this code some kind of command pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, command-pattern

I have a method that needs to execute multiple tasks to achieve a bigger task. Each task could be around 20-30 lines of code, so I decided to have a class per task.

```
public void bigTask() {
    TaskProcessor executor = new TaskProcessor();
    executor.addTask(new Task1(some arguments here));
    executor.addTask(new Task2(some other arguments here));
    executor.addTask(new Task2(some other arguments here));
    executor.run();
}

public interface Task {
    public void execute();
}

public class Task1 implements Task {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        //Some code here
    }
}

public class Task2 implements Task {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        //Some other code here
    }
}

public class Task3 implements Task {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        //Some other code here
    }
}

public class TaskProcessor implements Serializable {

    private List<Task> tasksList;

    public TaskProcessor () {
        this.tasksList = new ArrayList<Task>();
    }

    public void addTask(Task task) {
        this.tasksList.add(task);
    }

    public void execute() {
        for (Task task : this.tasksList) {
            task.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

For me, this code is like a command pattern, but I am not sure because the arguments for each task are of different types, unlike the traditional command pattern.

Do you think this could be considered a command pattern implementation?
Do you think this approach is OK for splitting a big method?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, this looks like it might fit within the command pattern.  The whole point of the `Task` interface is that you _don't_ need to worry about the implementation.  You only need to know that each `Task` implementation in fact has an `execute()` method.

Comment: You can let individual Tasks to register themselves to TaskExecutor passed to them
e.g.
    public Task1(TasksExecutor executor){executor.addTask(this);}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you think this could be considered a command pattern implementation?

I think it is "command pattern" enough.

> Do you think this approach is OK for splitting a big method?

We used a very similar approach to dissect long "sequences" small "Actions". But we added different kind of "containers". As in: sometimes I have a sequence of Actions that should continue to be executed, even when one entry fails. In other cases, the whole sequence should stop immediately. Another flavor is a sequence where each Action also has a an `undo()` method, so that the sequence container can do a rollback of all previous (passed) Actions when some Action fails.

Depending on your context, you might be "good to go", but I think you should at least consider what/if your indvidual Tasks can *fail*, and how your TaskProcessor container should react to failing steps.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of *structure*, this code is an application of the Command design pattern. The mapping to the pattern participants in the Gang of Four book is as follows:

- `Task` is the `Command` interface in the pattern, with its `execute` method;
- `Task1-3` are the concrete commands;
- `TaskProcessor` is the `Invoker`, which "asks the command to carry out the request"

However, in terms of *intent*, there is a bit of a mismatch. The original intent of the Command Pattern as stated in the Gang of Four book is

> Encapsulate a request as an object, thereby letting you parameterize clients with different requests, queue or log requests, and support undoable operations.

However, the question "Do you think this approach is OK for splitting a big method?" suggests the goal is to provide a modular decomposition of a complex piece of computing, which isn't the same.